# Virtual service is not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have one cluster with 3 pods and 3 services (first, second and third).

my services are:

```
aks-helloworld-first cluster ip:10.67.251.251
aks-helloworld-sec cluster ip:10.67.248.67                                       
aks-helloworld-third cluster ip: 10.67.240.154
```

the pods are:

```
aks-helloworld-first selector:app=helloworld-first
aks-helloworld-sec  selector: app=helloworld-sec
aks-helloworld-third   selector: app=helloworld-third
```

I added the following virtual service:

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld-first-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - aks-helloworld-first
  http:
  - match:
    - sourceLabels:
        app: helloworld-third
    route:
    - destination:
        host: aks-helloworld-first
```

I expected to be able to access to "first" only through "third".
But when trying to access to "first" through "second" I was able to do it as well.

I run kubectl exec to the "second" pod and run: curl -v http://10.67.251.251
I was able to access the "first" pod

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show how you are accessing the services (commands used)? It would be helpful to show pod and service information as well as the labels / selectors may be relevant.

Comment: i added all the info in the original question - thanks a lot!

Comment: In your example you seem to be bypassing any Istio Ingress altogether. Your are supposed to use the Ingress IP with the hostname defined under `hosts`. It doesn't dictate any traffic direct from pod to pod or service to service.

Comment: Andy i dont understand , in virtual service examples i found they dont use the ingress IP in the virtual service  definition.                                                             for example:   
[link] https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/bookinfo/networking/virtual-service-all-v1.yaml                                                                                                 can you please explain again what should i do different and why?

Comment: i still need assistance..

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Service is a set of rules for routing external traffic.

It seems, that you want to isolate one pod from another. And for this you might need to set up [**NetworkPolicy**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

By default, all pods are non-isolated; they accept traffic from any source.
That's why

> I run kubectl exec to the "second" pod and run: curl -v
>   http://10.67.251.251 I was able to access the "first" pod

Pods become isolated by having a NetworkPolicy that selects them.

For example, to accomplish

> access to "first" only through "third"

You'll need this NetworkPolicy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helloworld-first
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: helloworld-third
    ports:
    - my-http
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! what about using istio authorization (servicerole and servicerolebinding) in order to  isolate one pod from another?

Comment: Istio authorization is not about pod isolation, it is about performing policy enforcement on namespace/service/method -https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authz-http/